# How to extract links of each element from a dynamic web page?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

How can I extract a link to each item from a dynamic web page, since links only appear when you click on the item, and if I do that, I will go to the other page for each item (i.e. the page for each of the item links) )،Then return to the home page, which is an exhausting process.

I used selenium python for this and used Find the items I want and click on them  using click () method ،But it takes me to that item's page, and then I use the command  driver.back() To return to the first page, but it is tiring, takes a long time, and does not often work. I cannot extract the link for each item because it is a dynamic web page. The link to the item does not appear until after clicking on it.

Comment: Without HTML and your Selenium script, there is not much we can do.